# TryValidateModel not assigning object, returning all nulls, MVCStore Example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In the Checkout Controller I have the code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var order = new Order();
        TryValidateModel(order);
     ....
```

The model looks like this

```
[Bind(Exclude="OrderId")]
public partial class Order
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage= "First Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Address is required")]
    [StringLength(70)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal Code is required")]
    [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Country is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage= "Phone is required")]
    [StringLength(24)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Email Address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage="Email is not valid.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I can stop right before the TryValidateModel line and look at form values like

```
? Request.Form["FirstName"]
 "Michael"
 ? values["FirstName"]
   "Michael"
```

So why does TryValidateModel(order); return false and the order object does not get populated?

**Update**
To clarify my question I know false means it can not bind but I do not know why it can not bind.  Or that it should through the TryValidateModel(or even the ValidateModel)

But what is interesting is that if I change my method signature to

```
 public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(Order order)
```

order gets populated correctly.  So if it is able to bind in the Method call why not TryValidateModel(or even the ValidateModel)?

I am using MVC 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TryValidateModel` returns `false` when validation of the `Form Model` against your `Orders Model` Fails, thus Binding fails.

I hate using

```
TryValidateModel(order);
```

and prefer

```
    ValidateModel(order);
```

early on while developing my page, because binding is a delicate process. This way, if the model fails to bind, I get an exception and an indicative error msg.

Comment: Good idea, but the error message was not that helpful.  The model of type 'MvcMusicStore.Models.Order' is not valid, no inner exception.

Comment: @Mike, But it answers your question. The binding failed and you got no model because validation failed.